# Select element by tag/classname length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select an element using javascript/jquery in [Tampermonkey.](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvwMqBvJvWAhVrOpoKHb3vCzYQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Ftampermonkey%2Fdhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo&usg=AFQjCNFJnlmYB9TwxoirGBhJ6pVW0LfH9Q)

The class name and the tag of the elements are changing each time the page loads.
So I'd have to use some form of regex, but cant figure out how to do it.

This is how the html looks like:

```html
<ivodo class="ivodo" ... </ivodo>
<ivodo class="ivodo" ... </ivodo>
<ivodo class="ivodo" ... </ivodo>
```

- The tag always is the same as the classname.
- It's always a 4/5 letter random "code"

I'm guessing it would be something like this:
$('[/^[a-z]{4,5}/}')

Could anyone please help me to get the right regexp?

Comment: Could you not select the element based on their parent? Eg. `#parent > *`

Comment: This resulted in a much simpler code. Thank you!

$('.parent > *:contains(CommonText)').hide()

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use regexp in selectors. You can pick some container and select its all elements and then filter them based on their class names. This probably won't be super fast, though.

I made a demo for you:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZXdrL?editors=1010

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <abc class="abc">abc</abc>
  <abdef class="abdef">abdef</abdef>
  <hdusf class="hdusf">hdusf</hdusf>
  <ueff class="ueff">ueff</ueff>
  <asdas class="asdas">asdas</asdas>
  <asfg class="asfg">asfg</asfg>
  <aasdasdbc class="aasdasdbc">aasdasdbc</aasdasdbc>
</div>
```

js (with jQuery):

```
const $elements = $('.container *').filter((index, element) => {
  return (element.className.length === 5);
});

$elements.css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this would be to select those dynamic elements based on a fixed parent, for example:

```
$('#parent > *').each(function() {
  // your logic here...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the rules by which these tags are constructed are reliably as you state in the question, then you could select all elements then filter out those which are not of interest, for example :

```
var $elements  = $('*').filter(function() {
    return this.className.length === 5 && this.className.toUpperCase() === this.tagName.toUpperCase();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/twL8d5fq/1/)**

Of course, you may want initially to select only the elements in some container(s). If so then replace `'*'` with a more specific selector :

```
var $elements  = $('someSelector *').filter(function() {
    return this.className.length === 5 && this.className.toUpperCase() === this.tagName.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in vanilla JS
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cipoqowuvu/edit?html,js,output)

Check the demo dev tools console

```
<body>
  <things class="things">things</things>
  <div class="stuff">this is not the DOM element you're looking for</div>
</body>
```

### JS

```
// Grab the body children
var bodyChildren = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].children;

// Convert children to an array and filter out everything but the targets
var targets = [].filter.call(bodyChildren, function(el) {
  var tagName = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var classlistVal = el.classList.value.toLowerCase();
  if (tagName === classlistVal) { return el; }
});

targets.forEach(function(el) {
// Do stuff
  console.log(el)
})
```